# Cycles rendering is too slow

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have **GeForce GTX960M,
RAM: 16 GB,
Intel Core i7-6700HQ 2.60 GHz**.
I am rendering simple scenes, from Grant Abbitt, Blender Guru, and the likes' tutorials however, my render takes so much time and it is really discouraging to work with that pace. I can't even preview, I **have to wait 10-15 minutes** to see if my materials look good or not.
Please, suggest me some solutions. What do I need to do? Upgrading sure will partially solve it but I want to hear solutions other than upgrading, please.
**Is the specs that I have really not compatible to learn 3D?**

Comment: This might help                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60

Comment: It's all about your hardware and your render settings. I guess your CPU is even faster than your graphics card and Cycles prefers a graphics card...  Have you compared the two already? The render region feature might be helpful in your case: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#editors-3dview-navigate-render-region Each scene is different so hard to give any advice in general besides share your scene to compare against and: rendering takes time.